# Regular Expression that find string that dont start with " with before numbers

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

i have a string like this.

```
1 2 3 4 5 "Test test"

1 2 3 4 5 Test test"
```

I need to find the second string, that dont start with " and before have the numbers.

I read many topics of stack overflow but i dont find the answer for me.
Reg exp have to work on visual studio code for a txt.
Thanks so much for your help

I tried:

```
^(?![0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+")
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What programming language? Are you really using `Qt` and the `QRegularExpression` class?

Comment: To use in Visual Studio Code on a txt for example.

Comment: Use a negative lookahead that matches a sequence of digits and spaces followed by `"`

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I tried with ^[?![0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t+"] but nothing.

Comment: That's not a negative lookahead.

Comment: You've confused `[]` with `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. You need to change the outer `[]` to `()`. You also need to put `.*` after the negative lookahead to match the rest of the line when the lookahead fails.

And you don't have tabs between the numbers, you have spaces, so `\t` should be `\s`.

```
^(?![0-9]+\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\s+").*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/DxEPYd/1)

Comment: this can be shorter `^(?!(?:\d+\s){5}\s*").*`

Comment: This matches the following strings, `1 2 3 "Test test"`, `"Test test"`, `1 2 3 4 5 6 "Test test"`, `1 2 3 "Test test"` and `1 2 3 4 5"Test test"`. That may be the desired behavior but the question is not specific enough to make that determination. Toriga, this is a question for you: "do you want the strings I have listed to match"?

Answer (score 1):

It can be tricky to match on what isn't there, because *everything* that doesn't match a pattern is a match for the negation of that pattern.

You are looking for runs of digits followed by runs of whitespace, and this sequence itself repeats

```
(\d+\s+)+
```

You want the above to be followed by anything `.*` that *doesn't* start with a digit, whitespace or the double-quote character `[^\d\s"]`.

```
([^\d\s"])
```

Put it together

```
(\d+\s+)+([^\d\s"].*)
```

You can also make groups non-capturing. This has no logical effect but is more efficient of memory because it doesn't store the resolved groups as it searches the potential parse tree. This can be significant on large documents, especially when backreference cause deep recursion.

```
(?:\d+\s+)+(?:[^\d\s"].*)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made the following assumptions about what is required.

- the string must begin with one one or more instances of one or more digits followed by 1 or more spaces; and
- the last instance of one or more digits followed by one or more spaces must be followed by a character that is not a digit, space or double quote.

That can be tested by the following regular expression.

```
^(?:\d+ +)+[^"\d ].*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ezMDcX/1/)

As shown a the link, this regular expression matches the last three strings below, but not the first three.

```
1 2 3 4 5 "Test test
11 22 33 44 "Test test"
 11 22 33 44 The test"

1 2 3 4 5 Test test"
1 2 3 4 5 The "Test test"
11 22 33 44    The "Test test"
```

Comment: I suggest \s rather than a literal space. The spec is vague on tabs which means if you don't handle them they will occur, plus \s is easier to read than a literal space which is terribly vulnerable to "help" from fancy editors.

Comment: @Peter, those are valid points, but sometimes `\s` used to match a space causes a problem by matching a newline, which is also a consideration. Of course, one could always write `[\t ]`. If you use an editor that has a mind of its own I would think its settings need adjustment or it may be time for a change.

Comment: One usually adjusts the settings just _after_ figuring out the aftermath of surprise help. This happens once per gotcha per rebuild. On more than one occasion I have promised myself I would maintain a list but it doesn't happen, partly because the toolchain and the platform are also evolving. Both of us have made worthwhile observations here, the tragedy is that we are both preaching to the choir, on account of only the choir knows what we're rattling on about.